# solve the following diff eqn $(\sin x\sin y -xe^y)dy=(e^y+\cos x\cos y)dx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me solve this problem.I remember solving ths problem earlier but somehow i am not able to solve it.

Comment: This is an exact equation.

Comment: You should take a look at [MathJax basics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your question, just to make it more readable.

Comment: Please include what you have tried and what methods are available to you.

Comment: What have you tried? PLEASE put in some effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-arrange and group a little according to the nature of the terms you get
$$
0=[xd(e^y)+e^yd(x)]+[d(\sin x)\cos y+\sin x \,d(\cos y)]
$$
Now identify with the product rule.